# Can't import modules into python

Tags: python, atom-editor

I cannot seem to import packages in atom, does anyone else has this problem, or does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: This isn't a problem with Atom itself because it is clearly able to import the regular expression module from python. Make sure that the PyPDF2 module is actually / correctly installed

Comment: check where you installed PyPDF2 and make sure sys.path points to that directory.